# Mostrar datos de usuario logueado en php

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando mostrar un datos que tiene el usuario conectado, pero no lo consigo. Lo que quiero mostrar es el texto de la alerta que tiene ese usuario conectado. Como veis e hecho un `print_r` y me sale `SELECT alerta FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='test@gmail.com'`, el usuario lo tengo asignado al email de usuario. Me sale el usuario conectado, pero no devuelve la alerta de ese usuario.

Esta es la SOLUCIÓN, NADIE pensó en lo que dije de que el usuario de la sesión estaba ligado al email:

```
<?php session_start();

include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';
if (!isset ($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header('Location: ../login.php');
};


$sql_leer = "SELECT alerta FROM usuarios WHERE email='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'";


$gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
$gsnet->execute();

$resultado = $gsnet->fetchAll();



?>



                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">

                            <?php echo $resultado?>

                              </div>
```

Comment: El nombre del usuario no me vale, por que puede haber muchos que se llamen igual, me interesa que el usuario vaya ligado al email, pero la cuestión no es esa, la cosa es que no me imprime la alerta que tiene asociada a ese usuario

Comment: Prueba a hacer un var_dump($resultado) antes del foreach a ver que trae. Me suena haber visto este código en una pregunta anterior?

Comment: Me trae esto. array(0) { }

Comment: Entonces no hay resultados, por eso no printa nada al recorrer el array, está vacío. Si lanzas la query directamente en MySQL si te da resultados?

Comment: No entiendo por que no coge nada, cuando en alerta hay un texto...en ese usuario, si lanzo la query sin el $Session['usuario'], si que me muestra las alertas que hay en la base de datos, pero yo solo quiero me muestre la del usuario logueado

Comment: Que raro, porque el print que haces de la sentencia SQL muestra que es correcta la escritura. Se me ocurren dos pruebas, la primera guardar el valor de la sesión en una variable intermedia y usar esta para la consulta. La segunda no usar preparación de sentencia para un select.

Comment: dame un ejemplo please

Comment: Nadie más puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias causas por las que el código puede estar fallando. Puede ser la consulta preparada que no está escrita correctamente, puede ser que no haya coincidencia de datos, etc.

El código es mejorable en varios puntos:

- La consulta no es segura
- No tiene sentido usar `fetchAll` si se trata de una sola columna, es preferible usar `fetchColumn`
- No tiene sentido usar un bucle si esperas una sola fila
- He usado un solo bloque de código (PHP) concatenando una variable. Eso evita la fea mezcla de PHP/HTML.

El código sería este:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (!isset ($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        header('Location: ../login.php');
    };

    $usuario=(!empty($_SESSION['usuario'])) ? $_SESSION['usuario'] : NULL;
    if ($usuario){
        include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';
        if($pdo){
            $sql_leer = "SELECT alerta FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?";
            if ($gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer)){
                if ($gsnet->execute([$usuario])){
                    $resultado = $gsnet->fetchColumn();
                    $strHTML=($resultado) ? '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$resultado.'</div>' : "No hay datos con el criterio buscado";
                }else{
                    $strHTML="Error en la ejecución de la consulta: ".$gsnet->errorInfo()[2];
                }
            }else{
                $strHTML="Error preparando la consulta: ".$pdo->errorInfo()[2];
            }
        }else{
            $strHTML="No existe conexión a la base de datos";
        }
    }else{
        $strHTML="No existe usuario en la variable de sesión";
    }
    echo $strHTML;
?>
```

Todavía se puede refinar, controlando por ejemplo que la preparación de la consulta se hizo bien o capturando los errores. También, cuando no hay resultados `fetchColumn` retorna `FALSE`, se podría establecer un control para definir qué hacer en esos casos, que también son posibles cuando el criterio no se cumple.

Comment: Me sigue dando fallo, no coge los datos de la columna alerta y el var_dump me da un booleano (false)

Comment: @IvanInceraMundogamer debe haber algo mal en tu código original, o bien la conexión no está funcionando, o un nombre de tabla o de columna mal escrito. Te propondré un código con control estricto que te informe del problema.  Editando..............   ..........

Comment: @IvanInceraMundogamer ahora el código debería informar de cualquier cosa que ocurra dentro de él. Revisa la edición.

Comment: He probado tu código y me dice que no hay datos en el criterio buscado, pero es meramente imposible cuando la columna alerta tiene un dato metido...
Y no entiendo el por qué por que las demás consultas que he hecho, están bien y funcionan correctamente...

Comment: El código es infranqueable tal y como está escrito ahora , si te dice eso, es eso. Haz un `var_dump($usuario);` y verifica el dato que hay en la variable, no solo el valor sino también el tamaño. A veces hay espacios en blanco y cosas de ese tipo. O letras en mayúscula/minúscula que hacen que la comparación falle si la columna es case sensitive, o caracteres extraños debido a que no estas manejando bien la codificación. Para descartar esto último basta con que pruebes poniendo en el `WHERE` una columna numérica. O poniendo *a mano* el usuario.

Comment: He hecho una consulta en sql dentro de la base de datos y creo que se cual es el problema. La session del usuario va ligada al email por que al ver muchos usuarios que se llaman igual lo hice así, no puedo hacer restrinciones de nombres. Cuando he hecho una consulta en SQL con el email poniendo WHERE email o WHERE usuario, me aparece el dato de la columna alerta, algo está cogiendo mal

Comment: Lee mi comentario anterior. Haz el var_dump como te he dicho y revisa la codificación también de tu objeto `$pdo`. Siempre conviene ponerle utf-8 a la conexión cuando la creas . Aunque está claro que lo que comentas es un error de diseño de tu BD que deberás corregir.

Comment: El var_dump me da esto buscadobool(false)  mi $PDO:
$link = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=drivers_parade_club';

$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($link,$usuario,$contraseña);
   
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

Comment: No se si el problema es que no me está cogiendo el usuario conectado, pero no debería tener ese problema ejecutando el $Session no? Pero hice una consulta y en session usuario me salia el email del usaurio conectado, nose... me estoy volviendo loco...

Comment: ¿Dices que el `var_dump($usuario);` da `false`? Para clarificar lo que hay en la variable de sesión puedes hacer un `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Nada, si me lo da, no se donde puede estar el fallo. Las demás conexiones de la base de datos que he hecho están bien, pero solo no funcionan las que intento hacer con el usuario conectado...

Comment: Tengo la solución en vez de $sql_leer = "SELECT alerta FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=$SESSION['usuario']" es $sql_leer = "SELECT alerta FROM usuarios WHERE email=$SESSION['usuario']" dado que la sesion del usuario va ligado al email

Comment: @IvanInceraMundogamer es importante que entiendas la **esencia del error**  la cual radicaba en que estabas **usando la columna equivocada**. Si aplicas el mismo código de mi respuesta, cambiando la consulta así: **`SELECT alerta FROM usuarios WHERE email=?`**, funcionará y estarás usando un código seguro. Pasar la consulta con el criterio es un grave riesgo de seguridad llamado **Inyección SQL**. [En mi primer comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183015/mostrar-datos-de-usuario-logueado-en-php/183040?noredirect=1#comment342938_183040) te dije que revisaras los nombres de columna